# Issue: change border color or box stroke for unfocused TextInputLayout in android

Tags: android, textview, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, android-textattributes

I have a very specific issue for changing the outline of the textbox for TextInputLayout when it's unfocused. I can't seem to find an attribute to change the color for the border of my "unfocused" text box.

Here's a visual example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

The color of this (textbox):border is not white. currently its not focused.
After I click it, it turns white:

[image]

I don't know what I need to change, it doesn't seem like there is an attribute to change it.

I'm also using material design text input layout styles, although I don't see if that will affect it.

Here is my xml code for the text box:

```
 <other layouts ... >
     <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/item_recycler_view">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/dialog_text_input_layout"
                style="@style/Widget.AppTheme.TextInputLayoutList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Quick Add..."
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorWhite"
                app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorWhite"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                >

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/dialog_edit_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
 </other layouts...>
```

And here are the styles that I use for this:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.AppTheme.TextInputLayout.HintTextAlt" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle2">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.AppTheme.TextInputLayoutList" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppTheme.TextInputLayout.HintTextAlt</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">5dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">5dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">5dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Thanks, any help or suggestions are welcome!

Comment: try to use set focus method

Comment: @Amjad I'm not sure what a focus method is, do you have any examples?

Comment: if you want to make it focused at the beginning you may set attribute

Comment: setting it to focusable doesn't work :(

Comment: Sory, I mean the attribute android:focusedByDefault="true" . it will be focused at the begining

Comment: if you want to change the default color in unfocused mode state see my answer to this question.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

If you want to set the color for the outline box in unfocused mode instead of the default black, you have to add this line in `colors.xml` file which will override the default color for the outline box.

*copy this line as it is. you can change color to what you want.*

```
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color">#fff</color>
```

until now it will work, for more control on TextInputLayout you may add this style in styles.xml

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
</style>
```

then add theme to TextInputLayout

```
android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! This worked for me! If I may ask, how did you find this?

Comment: @VarunGovind you are welcome, and hope to vote this answer up, it really helps me, for more information you can see this issue discussion in github [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/112) and for more default values in color.xml you may visit [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/res/values/colors.xml) or [visit](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) for more information.

Comment: not working for me. it changes color when selected but default color stays black

Comment: @akshaybhange you can use **override** in that command: `<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true">#fff</color>`

Comment: How can I set the same programmatically?

Comment: '<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color">#fff</color>' but this will change all TextInputLayout to white what if i want to change it in a singel activity or fragment ?

Comment: @Arpan Did you find a way to change it only in one activity or fragment? Since I also need to change its color only on one screen.

Answer (score 44):

With the Material Components Library just use the **`boxStrokeColor`** attribute.
It can work with a selector.

Just use something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color"
        ..>
```

with:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/...." android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/...." android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/...." android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/...."/>  <!-- unfocused -->
</selector>
```

[image][image]

Comment: For everybody that wants to know this can be applied individually to each particular TextInputLayout in your project. Just make separate .xml files for your colors, so text_input_layout_stroke_green, text_input_layout_stroke_yellow, text_input_layout_stroke_red, etc. Then you customise each particular file's colors inside those xml files. Hope it helps someone =)

Comment: not working for matherial theme

Comment: @AnkitaSingh Are you sure? Which theme are you using in your app?

Answer (score 24):

[Answer from Amjad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52194924/527808) was right, but starting from [1.1.0-alpha02](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material) (probably even alpha01) after this [issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/112) was resolved it's possible to define color in color state list using the same `boxStrokeColor` attribute, e.g. how it's done in lib:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Usage:

```
...
app:boxStrokeColor="@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color"
...
```

Comment: How to add this selector to the TextInputLayout?

Comment: For any newbie here, the selector ```text_input_layout_stroke_color``` must be created inside ```res/color```, NOT ```res/drawable```

Answer (score 9):

```
app:boxStrokeColor="#000000"
app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0.5dp"
app:boxStrokeWidth="0.5dp"
```

This will make the box color constant event it is focused!

Comment: no, incorrect, it should be different color