# Android, why does app:boxStrokeColor in android material textinputlayout doesn't work?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android

I want to change the color of Material `TextInputLayout` stroke, but apparently it doesn't seem to work with `app:boxStrokeColor`. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: you can use "android:theme:" attribute , please follow this answer : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175748/issue-change-border-color-or-box-stroke-for-unfocused-textinputlayout-in-androi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If attribute `boxStrokeColor` is not a color state list but only a single color, its value will be applied only to the box's focus state.

You should define a **selector**:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/orange" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/...." android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/...." android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/...."/>
</selector>
```

and then apply it to the `boxStrokeColor` attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
       app:boxStrokeColor="@color/selector"
       ...>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

“app:boxStrokeColor” parameter changes stroke color in the focused state only, to cahnge the default state of the stroke, so you shoulde override mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color color by adding the below line to the color.xml file:

```
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true"> your color </color>
```

Comment: It is not correct. You don't have to override the default value.