# Issue: Change the border color or box stroke of TextInputLayout when unfocused

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

**Problem statement***I have this TextInputLayout and its initial box stroke color is black by default but I want it to be of specific color as I have two themes for my application.
I have specified boxstroke colors in style file but its not applying when unfocused.*

**What I found on internet**
I found this answer help full: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52194924/14254287)

Overwriting default color of textinputlayout:

```
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color">#fff</color>
```

**Question ?**
**As I have different themes in my application I need to change this dynamically.**(*orange for light theme and white for dark theme*)

Reference Images from: [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52175748/14254287)

**Unfocused Black box stoke**
[image: Initial Black box stoke]

**Focused White box stoke**
[image: Focused White box stoke]

*For now I am setting default color to lite gray so it can match both of themes*

Comment: Have you tried using ColorStateList instead of just color reference?